# Unknown iOS errors in my Custom Class

Tags: objective-c

I ran into an issue with my project and cannot figure out what is causing the errors.
I am building a social media application which involves users and images.

I created a custom class called "Portfolio" amongst a few other custom classes.
The project has been building fine. Just yesterday, I tried building/archiving the project and I got numerous errors within the "Portfolio" class only. I checked my Compile sources and the file is there, not highlighted red.

I imported the class to a couple ViewControllers. One ViewController indicates that the class doesn't exist, the other does.

I am using Parse.com to store my data, but I don't think this has anything to do with it.

My code is below, and the errors I'm getting are underneath it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface Portfolio : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

+(NSString *)parseClassName;

@property (strong, nonatomic)PFFile *portfolioImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic)PFUser *user;


+(void)getImagesForUser:(PFUser *)user inBackgroundWithBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *images, NSError *error))block;


@end
```

Errors:

Expected Selector for Objective-C method

Expected Method Body

Unexpected @ in program

Missing Context for method declaration

@end must appear in an Objective-C context

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project `Shift + Command + K`? Based on the errors, it seems like you might by trying to declare properties/methods in an implementation(.m) file instead of your interface(.h) file. Just a guess.

Comment: You've got an open closure or some type of missing syntax somewhere that is causing the overall format of files to be misread. It's likely in the one view controller you mention, but without specific errors and code any guess would be useless.

Comment: I think you need to delete the project from your simulator and run it again.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else in your project. Since it looks like a parsing error, check to make sure you didn't import a `.m` file instead of a `.h`. Cleaning and rebuilding may help. I would also delete the derived data for the project.